# Istio set response header with envoy filter

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I want set a response header in Istio .
In my company they are doing it like that.

```
  - applyTo: HTTP_FILTER
    match:
      context: SIDECAR_INBOUND
```

So my first question.

Why are they setting context: Inbould ??

All the requests leaving the cluster should be set with response header .
So shouldn't it be SIDECAR_OUTBOUND ??

And what is the difference between context  SIDECAR and Gateway ??

Comment: You can also use Virtual Service: https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/virtual-service/#Headers

Comment: Sidecar outbound is when your service is calling another service

Comment: Configurations can be applied at sidecar and gateway level.  For responses can be outbound.  The envoy filter details https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/envoy-filter/#EnvoyFilter-PatchContext  you can also check envoy documentation